# Facebook /PROFILE_ID/links is not working with friend id

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

```
Iam using this code for sharing a link to my wall

$args = array(
            'message'   => 'message here',
            'link'      => 'http://www.example.com/',
        );
        $result = $facebook->api("/me/links", "post", $args);
```

It is successfully sharing this link on my wall.if i want to share a link on my friends wall i have used this code

```
$result = $facebook->api("/friend_id/links", "post", $args);
```

But it is not sharing this link on my friends wall...is their any way to do this

Comment: I sincerely doubt it, otherwise you could write an app to spam peoples walls!

Comment: Why are you keep posting same problem?

Comment: But in facebook document they mention we can use this code http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Answer (score 0):

Lint the access token you're using and post the results here.  You may not be requesting the correct permissions.

Comment: Iam getting this error  Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#240) Requires a valid user is specified (either via the session or via the API parameter for specifying the user. thrown in /var/www/bbank/pga_fb_app/app/vendors/base_facebook.php on line 1039

Comment: Hmm, that's not the same thing I see when I lint an access token.  Please provide the complete listing, there's more information that just permisssions listing.  You may be using a USER access token when you really need a PAGE access token.

Comment: $ret = $this->facebook->api('/100001281742604/links', 'POST', array(
           'access_token' => 'AAADuZAExGbfYBAFMJDuOQrSXAKybfxbZBBckUbI6kb08MOQ9bseHzemCsUSpc7PRFlF8VZAZBzZA6UBvsixgSnxHeWXPsraSuZCe1ZAnkc6GAZDZD ',
                                          'link' => 'http://yahoo.com',
                                          'message' => 'Testtt',
                                          'picture'=>'',
                                          'name'=>'Jerin Davis',
                                          
                                          
                                   ));

Comment: So is that a PAGE access token or a USER one?

Comment: Does using that same token via the Graph API Explorer work for that action?

Comment: in graph api explore i used this code https://graph.facebook.com/profile_id/links showing the same error - Requires a valid user is specified (either via the session or via the API parameter for specifying the user

Comment: Ok, so then your code is fine.  One of three things if the Graph API explorer doesn't want to do it as well as your app doesn't want to do it.  1) Not allowed by API. 2) Wrong access token. 3) Graph API broken.